# ViewPager2 How to implement infinite scroll in both direction?

Tags: android

I use this library in my project https://github.com/IslamKhSh/CardSlider
I need to implement infinite scroll in both direction.
I tried to find some implemention from stackoverflow, but none of them helped to me.

I tried 2 solution in both my app freezed.

1 solution:

```
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = Integer.MAX_VALUE

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PrizeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (items.size > 0)
            holder.bind(items[position % items.size])
    }
```

2 solution:

```
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = if (items.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.MAX_VALUE

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PrizeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position % items.size])
    }
```

Maybe you know some alternative libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this feature like this.

```
    val items = ArrayList<Level>()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = if (items.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.MAX_VALUE

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position % items.size])
    }
```